# Is it possible to get more than 30 messages from stocktwits?

Tags: stocktwits

I saw on Stocktwits API documentation that they only allow to get mose recent 30 messages from stream. However, I need to extract messages by searching for certain user or certain symbols from stocktwits by specifying certain periods, etc. Jan,2017-Jan,2019. For example i want to extract all the messages sent by A user from 2017-2019 or all the messages with AAPL tag from 2017-2019. Is it possible?